# How to store a file on an SD card (external)

Tags: android, file, android-sdcard

I want to store a file on the SD card using `File`. I already achieved to store a file in external storage (named internal storage in my file explorer app. This is NOT the SD card).

I read much about storing data on SD cards and often saw:

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFile")
```

But this will store the file on external storage and not on the SD card. So how can I store a file on the SD card and not on external storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you use the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`) and let the *user* choose where the *user* wants to put this content. The user may wish to put the content somewhere else. For example, the user may not have removable storage.

Temporarily, you are welcome to use `getExternalFilesDirs()` and similar methods on `Context`. If these return 2+ elements, the second and subsequent ones are locations on removable storage. On Android 4.4+, your app can write to those locations without any particular permissions. Android Q is changing the rules here a lot, which is another reason to use the Storage Access Framework instead.

Comment: what is the parameter for and what do i have to set there

Comment: @JonasPTFL: I am not certain what parameter you are referring to. If you mean the parameter to `getExternalFilesDirs()`, pass in `null` or one of the `Environment.DIRECTORY_*` values, such as `Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC`. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context?hl=en#getExternalFilesDirs(java.lang.String)) for more.

Comment: Yes, sorry that was my bad! Ok, i passed null as parameter, but the method will return a array of files... What do i have to do with this?

Comment: @JonasPTFL: If it only has one element in the array, the user does not have any removable storage. If the user has 2+ elements in the array, the second and subsequent ones point to app-specific locations on removable storage. You can use those as base directories for creating files, subdirectories, etc.

Comment: Ok thank you very much! I achived to store the file on sd card, but in the Android/data/my.app.package/  folder... Can i also store it in main folder, where the Android folder is?

Comment: @JonasPTFL: "Can i also store it in main folder, where the Android folder is?" -- not usually. There is the occasional buggy device that allows this. If you use the Storage Access Framework, the *user* could choose the main folder, in which case you could use the `Uri` you get back from `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` to write your content there. The overall trend of Android -- particularly with Android Q -- is to give the *user* control over the *user's* device and the *user's* storage.

Answer (score -1):

Using this may help you:

[An answer to Stack Overflow question *How do I get the external storage's path?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28427340/7626390)

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)
```